# rest binding instead of soap binding

Tags: java, web-services, rest, soap

i used the tool java2ws from apache cxf to convert java to wsdl but it generates soap binding. How can i make it generate rest bindings ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSDLs are associated with [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) (think [JAX-WS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAX-WS)), while [WADL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language) is associated with REST. In my opinion, I would follow [JAX-RS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAX-RS) and implement the web service with something like [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/), although CXF does implement JAX-RS.

Answer (score 0):

Some answers wrt CXF here: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/restful-services.html

I'd advise against trying to automatically convert methods in an interface into a REST service. 
If you want to follow the RESTful architectural style, you need to think of your business objects as resources and you potentially have to come up with additional resources that are implicitly expressed in your service methods. (i.e. `order(Item);` might introduce a seperate `order` resource which requires changing the way you think about your business object model.